# Best choice to power an ESP32 board from an external power source

Tags: esp32

I'm looking for an efficient, external DC power supply for an ESP32 board.

I have two questions:

1. Is better, for power saving, to power the ESP32 at 3.3 V or 5 V?
2. What is a good efficient configuration for the DC power supply?

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ESP32 works from 3.3V supply only. Most of the ESP32 **boards** include a LDO (liner regulator) to accept 5V from USB also. But it's "native" chip supply are still 3.3V. So the most efficient power supply source would be a 3.3V. This answers you 1st question.

As for the 2nd - any switching PSU for a 3.3V shall be just fine if you are powering it from mains. If you are powering from battery it depends on the battery type.